# Is this a safe circuit for a RasPi? (Optocoupler diverting current from NPN base when on)

Tags: circuit-design

I have a circuit with a 11.3 V signal voltage and negligible current. I want to control the state of this circuit with a RasPi, importantly, **I want to hook it up to the RasPi so that whenever the RasPi is powered, the circuit is closed** (default fallback state) but if I run a script on the RasPi controlling the normally not powered GPIO pins I can start programmatically opening and closing the signal circuit. (This is because I want the signal to be closed if a script runs into an error.)

What I've came up with is this:

- the positive wire of the signal voltage is connected to the collector of an NPN transistor and the negative wire is connected to the emitter
- the base of the NPN is connected to the 3V3 power supply pin of the RasPi and the emitter is also connected to the ground (GND) pin of the RasPi.

If the RasPi is powered up, this means that the signal circuit is closed as enough current is supplied to the base pin of the NPN transistor.

But:

- I have also added an optocoupler, which can be turned on or off with a GPIO pin (so its anode is connected to the GPIO and its cathode is connected to the GND)
- and crucially, on the transistor side of the opto, the collector is connected to the same branch  where the base of the NPN gets its current
- while the emitter is connected to the GND
- and I added resistors so that the path through the optocoupler has much less resistance than the path through the NPN.

What this means is that whenever I turn on the GPIO voltage and so the optocoupler, its transistor side will divert current away from the branch that goes to the base pin of the NPN, so it will turn off.

Here is a schematic I've tried to draw, hopefully correctly:
[image]
(Two corrections: the GPIO branch can be turned on or off, so it essentially has a switch on it, but I didn't draw it, and it also supplies 3.3 volts when turned on.)

I actually built a very similar circuit like this (where I've diverted current from a LED's anode instead of the NPN base pin) on my RasPi + breadboard setup that worked. I have also modelled this version with the NPN in Tinkercad (https://www.tinkercad.com/things/f6g2uXV7PPf) and it seems to work. But I'd really appreciate some feedback on this, mostly whether it is safe for my RasPi.

(I am very much a beginner in this whole topic, so please forgive me if this whole setup is idiotic in some way.)

Comment: You'll get a much better response if you add a schematic to the question rather than describing your idea in words or even linking somewhere else.

Comment: @JohnD Thanks for the tip, I've tried my best...

Comment: Why are you using an opto-isolator?  It isn't isolating anything.

Comment: @JRE My idea was to have something I can turn on and off that controls the current diversion from the NPN transistor. Is there a way to leave out the opto and still have this control?

Comment: Just connect the GPIO  to the base of the transistor.  Set low to "divert current from the base." Set the GPIO to high impedance for "normal" operation of the transistor.

Comment: @JRE My thinking currently is this: in that case when the GPIO is not controlled programmatically, it won't emit current so the transistor won't close the signal circuit. Where am I wrong? Can I set the GPIO pins to emit current when the RasPi is simply under power, but not running any script? The signal circuit must be closed by default, when the RasPi is simply powered up.

Comment: You can replace the coupler with another NPN. What is the required response time and what is an acceptable voltage drop across the switch?

Comment: @Jens Right, I actually used the opto as I already had one, but I'd still need to buy the NPN so I could just buy two and lose the opto.

But in the meantime I've realized I could just very easily turn the logic of the signal voltage so that it could be off on default and on otherwise. So I'll just do that and use the opto without the NPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to drive a load and the Ground (GND) can be shared between the load and Raspberry, you can simply use a transistor to turn on/off the load:

[image: Simple switch]

Something to consider is if your load is indeed 10 Ohm, you might need a Darlington transistor to be able to do so. Otherwise, use needs a smaller R2, which will lead to a smaller R1, and the Raspberry would not be able to provide the current.

If your load is noisy, you need separated GND or for any reason you need the isolation, and then you should use the optocoupler. Your circuit seems to be working. However, it does not separate the GND, and you lose the benefits of optocoupler. You can do something like this:

[image: Optocoupler switch]

The optocoupler should be able to sink 10mA so this could work.

If you need the load to be connected to the ground or negative of the battery, you need to use a PNP transistor instead of Q1 and modify the input bias and optocoupler to switch that on/off.

Both of the circuits above will keep the load on by default. You need to make the Raspberry pin output. Then, for the first circuit set it to a Low level to turn the load off. For the second circuit, set it to High to turn off the load.

For low-voltage circuits like this where a load needs to be switched on/off, it's usually better to use a Mosfet instead of BJT. This way, you don't have to be worried about the BJT gain and base current. Find an n-channel Mosfet that can withstand the working conditions (current, voltages, temperature) and replace the BJT.